# How can I get count of child of a parent ID in MYSQL or specifically cake 1.3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working on a 3-way tree and my table structure is

```
+----+---------+-----------------------+
| id | user_id | leg_type|parent_user_id
+----+---------+-----------------------+
|  1 | 1011    |  M      |1000         |
|  2 | 1012    |  L      |1000         |
|  3 | 1013    |  R      |1000         |
|  4 | 1014    |  M      |1011         |
|  5 | 1015    |  R      |1011         |
|  6 | 1016    |  M      |1012         |
+----+---------+-----------------------+
```

Now I want to search for a specific ID let say parent_user_id(1000) how can I find number of child  in M,L and R

e.g 1000(M) = 1011,1014,1015{3}
    1000(L) = 1012,1016{2}
    1000(R) = 1013{1}

```
Array(
   "1000"=>Array(
           "M" => 3
           "L" => 2
           "R" => 1
           )
)
```

Any optimised solution. I tried everything but not worth.

Edited : Picture visualization

[image]

Comment: Post whichever of your attempts you think was the closest.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about cake php , but if its the query you can try the following

I have taken test as your table name

```
select `t1`.`parent_user_id`,`t1`.`leg_type`,count(`t1`.`leg_type`) as `leg_type_count` 
from `test` `t1`
inner join `test` `t2` on `t2`.`leg_type` = `t1`.`leg_type` 
AND `t1`.`parent_user_id` = `t2`.`parent_user_id` 
WHERE `t2`.`parent_user_id` = 1011
group by `t1`.`leg_type`
```

Here you can check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e9f0/7

Comment: result is not right for other values. Please try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77187/3/0
It should return 
1011(R)=1
1011(M)=1
but result is something else. Does that make sense ?

Comment: let me check what is the issue

Comment: My bad I am sorry, I had a small bug in the previous query, I have fixed this on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e9f0/18 and also updated my answer. Please check now

Comment: hmm I appreciate. But it still not right now check your fiddle for id 1000. Not desired result set. It gives 1,1,1 where as it should return  3,2,1. Not sure why is it happening. your query seems right to me even

Comment: If you look at your table parent id 1000 is associated with 1011.1012 and 1014, but you said its e.g 1000(M) = 1011,1014,1015{3}.. Could you please explain how 1000(M) is associated with 1011,1014,1015{3}

Comment: Please see the updated question. Hope it will clear you query

Comment: I tried every possible way with a single query but looks like it needs recursive query, which I do not think is possible with single query. May be stored procedure could help this.

Comment: hmm I also ended up with this conclusion that we needs recursive query, but i don't wants to use that. Moreover, I have never used stored procedure in mysql and cakephp. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Can you post your recursive query here

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a find on the children and then use Set::combine to order your results.

```
$array = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
    'User.parent_user_id' => 1000)));
```

And then do:

```
$array = Set::combine($array, '{n}.User.leg_type', '{n}.User.id', '{n}.User.parent_user_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried it, giving just one level data where as i want data for all the levels. Please see the example in the question

Comment: Well, past one level it starts to get really expensive to do this yourself. It'd probably be better to let CakePhp do the work for you.  Take a look at setting the parent_id and using $this->find('threaded')

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#find-threaded